# How do I insert a piece of code in Mathematica?

Tags: programming, packages

In Fortran, I can use `include "file"` to insert a piece of code. Is there a similar method in Mathematica?

Comment: Have a look at the docs on [packages](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/tutorial/MathematicaPackages.html).

Comment: @b.gatessucks I think that should be an answer...

Comment: @acl Can't do it right now, please do go ahead.

Answer (score 4):

The answer is very simple:

Put your external code snippet into a file `toInclude.m`, for example with the content

```
Plot[Sin[x],{x,0,Pi}]
```

Now in the "parent" notebook (assuming it's in the same directory as the code snippet), execute the command

```
Import["toInclude.m"]
```

or

```
<< "toInclude.m"
```

and you're done. Here are the references for [<< (`Get`)](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Get.html) and [Import](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Import.html).